Android WebRTC: App crash after reçeiving call
I'm developing an Android Native (kotlin) application that lets you make video calls using WebRTC and Amazon's voice assistant as a second peer. Calls work perfectly in one direction only (from the calling mobile to the voice assistant: createOffer case). However, I have a problem in the other case where I receive the call (when the voice assistant initiates the call: createAnswer case), the problem is that the audio doesn't reach the voice assistant properly, I have the impression that the phone's microphone sends and mixes the 2 audios (the one arriving from the video assistant and the one leaving from the phone) and therefore the audio that reaches the voice assistant is not at all understandable. What's more, after a while, my application crashes, the trace of which is as follows
05-30 17:22:11.771 21305 25475 E rtc     : #
05-30 17:22:11.771 21305 25475 E rtc     : # Fatal error in: ../../../../usr/local/google/home/sakal/code/webrtc-aar-release/src/audio/audio_send_stream.cc, line 412

I have the same problem using 3 different phones: One plus 8T (Android 13), Samsung A52S (Android 13) and Samsung Xcover 4s (Android 11). And I'm using this version of webrtc 1.0.32006
I've tried to look at the tracks and codecs used, but everything seems fine to me. Because it's the same configuration used in the case where the calls work perfectly (phone to voice assistant). The SDP generated when creating answer on the phone
 v=0

 o=- 6578108251971788474 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1

 s=-

 t=0 0

 a=group:BUNDLE audio video

 a=msid-semantic: WMS ARDAMS

 m=audio 38802 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVP 111 103 9 102 0 8 105 13 110 113 101

 c=IN IP4 109.19.240.116

 a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0

 a=candidate:514002099 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.1.22 38802 typ host generation 0 network-id 4 network-cost 10

 a=candidate:929978963 1 tcp 1518217471 2a02:8449:2f08:9009:4748:38c9:c383:ebcf 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 900

 a=candidate:842163049 1 udp 1686052607 109.19.240.116 38802 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.22 rport 38802 generation 0 network-id 4 network-cost 10

 a=ice-ufrag:DHQ/

 a=ice-pwd:lZhE70icdH7/O75eG2nSEZOr

 a=ice-options:trickle renomination

 a=fingerprint:sha-256 57:D3:D3:DF:08:4C:74:BF:A6:B3:4D:D5:F4:B0:6D:07:8E:0D:E5:B4:56:D1:8B:3C:76:9C:E4:BC:08:5D:5A:3B

 a=setup:active

 a=mid:audio

 a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level

 a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time

 a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01

 a=sendrecv

 a=rtcp-mux

 a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2

 a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc

 a=fmtp:111 maxaveragebitrate=48000;minptime=10;useinbandfec=1

 a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000

 a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000

 a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000

 a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

 a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

 a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000

 a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000

 a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000

 a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000

 a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000

 a=ssrc:1985491355 cname:0pYskyvJW5cu/PAH

 a=ssrc:1985491355 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSa0

 a=ssrc:1985491355 mslabel:ARDAMS

 a=ssrc:1985491355 label:ARDAMSa0

 m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVP 100 96 97 98 99 126 127 125 104

 c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0

 a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0

 a=ice-ufrag:DHQ/

 a=ice-pwd:lZhE70icdH7/O75eG2nSEZOr

 a=ice-options:trickle renomination

 a=fingerprint:sha-256 57:D3:D3:DF:08:4C:74:BF:A6:B3:4D:D5:F4:B0:6D:07:8E:0D:E5:B4:56:D1:8B:3C:76:9C:E4:BC:08:5D:5A:3B

 a=setup:active

 a=mid:video

 a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset

 a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time

 a=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientation

 a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01

 a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay

 a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type

 a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing

 a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space

 a=sendrecv

 a=rtcp-mux

 a=rtcp-rsize

 a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000

 a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb

 a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc

 a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir

 a=rtcp-fb:100 nack

 a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli

 a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;max-fs=4000;max-mbps=96000;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f

 a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000

 a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb

 a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc

 a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir

 a=rtcp-fb:96 nack

 a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli

 a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000

 a=fmtp:97 apt=96

 a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000

 a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb

 a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc

 a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir

 a=rtcp-fb:98 nack

 a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli

 a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000

 a=fmtp:99 apt=98

 a=rtpmap:126 rtx/90000

 a=fmtp:126 apt=100

 a=rtpmap:127 red/90000

 a=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000

 a=fmtp:125 apt=127

 a=rtpmap:104 ulpfec/90000

 a=ssrc-group:FID 277271886 4039293539

 a=ssrc:277271886 cname:0pYskyvJW5cu/PAH

 a=ssrc:277271886 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSv0

 a=ssrc:277271886 mslabel:ARDAMS

 a=ssrc:277271886 label:ARDAMSv0

 a=ssrc:4039293539 cname:0pYskyvJW5cu/PAH

 a=ssrc:4039293539 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSv0

 a=ssrc:4039293539 mslabel:ARDAMS

 a=ssrc:4039293539 label:ARDAMSv0

